# How can I plot a discrete probability distribution with Seaborn?

Tags: python, charts, bar-chart, seaborn

I want to plot a discrete probability distribution (a MWE below).

In order to keep the graphics consistent, I'd like to use `seaborn`.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

x = [2,3,5]
freq = [0.3,0.2,0.5]
df = DataFrame({'val.':x,'freq.':freq})
df.set_index('val.')
```

[image: dataframe]

Is there any way to produce a barplot of this distribution (other than generating data that have this distribution)?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use built-in dataframe plotting functions:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
x = [2,3,5]
freq = [0.3,0.2,0.5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'val.':x,'freq.':freq})
df.set_index('val.')['freq.'].plot.bar(rot=0)
```

Which produces:

[image: a <code>pandas</code> bar plot]

Another option using `seaborn`:

```
sns.barplot(data = df,x='val.',y='freq.')
```

[image: <code>seaborn</code> bar plot]